Warning: fsockopen(): when creating a WordPress Block
I'm getting a Connection refused error like this Warning: fsockopen(): Unable to connect to db5....lan:3809 (Connection refused) in /home/org/public_html/wp-content/db.php on line 1083
It started happening while creating a WordPress block.

The culprit was on render.php, the code was returning before the actual HTML took place:
<?php
$opt = get_option( 'my_option' );

if ( empty($opt) ) {
    return;
}


?>
<p>Hello.</p>

But here's the tricky part: that if condition evaluates to false.
So for instance, the following will also trigger the same Warning:
if ( false ) {
    return;
}


?>
<p>Hello.</p>

While I'm unsure why this happens, just make sure that any return is placed after some HTML has already been rendered.
